# What is the generic term for a 'Collector' gamer?

Tags: terminology

Is there a word or phrase to describe a player who plays for aesthetics? I'm talking about MMO players mainly, but it's also present in other game types.

For example, a player who:

- Resets his character and replays the game to see his name written in a different color.
- Is willing to spend more money for a collector's edition, because it has a custom skin or an aura on his character.
- Spends hours farming to get a cosmetic object or useless pet.

I am looking for a word to describe these players that play more for the collection that for the game.

Comment: so to be clear. you are asking for the "types" of gamers?

Comment: Yes, they are called smug. But that does not apply to gamers only :P

Comment: I think "Collector" is sufficient.  Not nay different than stamps, baseball cards, or other "useless" objects

Comment: I do all of those things because those are things I enjoy in games. Take World of Warcraft for example. I play pretty much to hunt down the vanity pets because I like collecting them. I often buy the collectors editions because I appreciate the game and considering the years of enjoyment I get out of the game an extra 20-30 bucks upfront is nothing when put over 3 years (thats what, a dollar a month?) I am not however an end-game grinder, I stay one addon behind and ignore it as I do not enjoy that part of the game.. Overall though I think people just call me a Gamer.. or nuts but whatever :)

Comment: This isn't really anything that's specific to gamers.  Every area has their own people that fit into these categories.  Like @Batophobia said, it can be applied to stamp collecting, baseball cards, just about anything at all.

Comment: Completionist fits the third bulletpoint and maybe first (cod prestidge badges come to mind). however the second bulletpoint defines collector.

Comment: These are three distinct aspects without correlation to one another. A "completionist" does not usually use more than one save slot 'to see their name in a different color', nor would they spend money to recieve 'an aura', but they would spend a long time collecting 'useless' or 'cosmetic' items of all sorts, but not for the cosmetic appeal if that's what you mean. You need to narrow your description down considerably, and maybe think a bit more about what you're really asking to better describe what you're looking for, if a word exists for it at all.

Comment: I still think this is opinion based as if such a term existed it would only be prevalent because it matches more people's opinions. such as the terms "PC Master Race" and "Dirty Console Peasant", these terms only exists because there are quite a few egotistical PC Gamers who think they are superior because they play PC games but in my opinion a  real gamer can not be confined to a system and look down on every other system. In terms of your question you, particularly with the last point Gamer Otaku (Otaku in Japan not the west) fits but that's my oppinion

Comment: Rolled back the invalid edits. If you want to discuss the question, use comments. If you want to discuss our policy, use Meta. Neither should be discussed by editing the question itself.

Comment: @B413 i think your focusing in the wrong part of the flag since the message is the generic SE one found on any site, you need to focus on the "rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.". the expertise will vary by type of game, your bullet points almost sound like that from an MMO which the answer would be different from someone who doesn't play MMO's, as such you can have 2 valid yet totally answers.

Comment: also "useless pet" would be opinionated itself, one of the dolls you can get to sit on your head in Ragnarok Odyssey may be useless to some but to me is a invaluable companion who sits on my head and keep me company during those hikes though missions, like a little Yochiro Kusagashi spuring me to "Fight On! Fight On!". the same with the Sophie Doll in Tales of Graces F. as such this may end up creating 2 different terms depending on the person's opinion on wether the cosmetic or pet is useless to them

Comment: Regarding the first bullet point, are you referring to the concept of Remorting? (Also familiar as Prestige in Call of Duty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completionist is probably be closest term you will get as they generally will get every single possible thing done within said game. It doesn't matter if it is an achievement or not, they will get **everything**.

This includes flavour text for displays and purchasing collectors editions just to get the bonus items.

Comment: gotta catch 'em all